# Is it possible to make an href jump on the same page with the destination element not having an id?

Tags: html, url, href, fragment-identifier

Is it possible to make an `<a href>` link to the same page when your destination doesn't have an ID?

```
<a href = "#">Jump to Topic 1</a>
...
<!--destination is below-->
<h1 class="tab-title" data-editor-style="title" style="color:#444444">Topic 1</h1>
```

Comment: Nope. You need an element with an id, or a named anchor element ('<a name="...">) as target.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, the answer is no. You need an ID or at least a name, like CBroe mentioned in a comment of your question.

However, I found this [here](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000049.htm):

> Today, all browsers recognize **top** as being the top of the page. If you
>   want the visitor to go to the very top of the page, the **ID tag can be
>   left** out and the A HREF link will **still work**.

Answer (score 0):

A URL fragment identifier can only target an element with a matching ID, or a corresponding named anchor. You cannot link to arbitrary elements without IDs. (There was a [proposal](https://www.w3.org/community/cssselfrags) that would have allowed the use of CSS selectors as fragment identifiers, in which I was personally involved, but it never took off.)

The best you can do is to use JavaScript to select the element you want and give it an ID that is reserved for your hyperlink. If the elements matching this selector will change then you will additionally have to listen for such changes and handle them accordingly, but that's probably beyond the scope of this question.